Elementor (free version) - How to edit accordion or toggle so when it's expanded it says "read less"
How would I go about making the Elementor toggle or accordion "link" read "show less/read less" when the item is expanded? Currently by default it just keeps the title of the name of the toggle or accordion item. Thanks!
I tried so many different youtube and online tutorials for expanding/read more/read less tutorials but they never work fully.
